# How to compre DateTime with generic times in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm working on a ruby on rails app that can automatically schedule events. Every event has a `start_time` datetime and an `end_time` datetime.

Here is the problem:

**In general, events shouldn't be scheduled before 9:00am or after 10:30pm. This is true for edge cases as well. I.e, even if an event ends after 9:00am, it shouldn't start before it. Similarly, if an event starts before 10:30pm, it should not go on passed 10:30pm.**

How can I go about making sure that *every* event fits this criteria, when some of these events are on different dates?

The problem i'm having is that, yes, a DateTime object has a date and a time associated with it. *But so does a Time object.*

This means that if I have an event with a start *and* end datetime between 9am and 10:30pm, my comparison will always return false if I'm comparing a time object with a datetime object of a different date.

Here is what I had in mind:

```
def event_out_of_bounds?(event_start_time, event_end_time, min_start_time, max_end_time)

if event_start_time.hour > max_end_time.hour then
  return true
end

if event_end_time.hour > max_end_time.hour then
  return true
end

if event_start_time.hour < min_start_time.hour then
  return true
end

if event_end_time.hour < min_start_time.hour then
  return true
end

return false

end
```

Problems with this code:

1. It doesn't take into account minutes. I.e., if I ever change `min_start_time` to 9:30 am, then this method won't work anymore.
2. There are different dates involved. `event_start_time` and `event_end_time`, **which are DateTimes**, obviously have the same date. *However*, `min_start_time` and `max_end_time`, **Which are created using Time.new** have a different date (I just default it `2020-01-01`). This wouldn't be a big problem if I knew beforehand what the dates would be for the events, however I won't in this case.

Any ideas for an algorithm to make this check elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> events shouldn't be scheduled before 9:00am or after 10:30pm.

I might use `Range#cover?` for this.

```rb
require 'active_support/all'

def validate_schedule(s, e)
  min = s.time_zone.local(s.year, s.month, s.day, 9, 0, 0)
  max = s.time_zone.local(s.year, s.month, s.day, 22, 30, 0)
  (min..max).cover?(s..e)
end

# Tests
et = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
t = ->(d, h, m) { et.local(2020, 2, d, h, m, 0) }
test = ->(s, e) { puts format('%s %s = %s', s, e, validate_schedule(s, e)) }
test[t[1, 8, 59], t[1, 22, 30]] # false, start too early
test[t[1, 9, 0], t[1, 22, 30]] # true, 10:30 pm ok
test[t[1, 9, 0], t[1, 21, 30]] # true, 9:30 pm also ok
test[t[1, 9, 0], t[1, 22, 31]] # false, end too late
test[t[1, 9, 0], t[2, 22, 30]] # false, no all night parties
```

If you allow multi-day events, simply calculate `max` from the end date (`e`) instead:

```rb
  max = e.time_zone.local(e.year, e.month, e.day, 22, 30, 0)
```

`Range.cover?` works with "any objects that can be compared using the `<=>` operator." (see [Custom Objects in Ranges](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.3/Range.html)

Comment: Yep, this worked! Interesting solution. I should've known to just copy the dates over when performing my comparisons. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Approach**

It's curious that the question is framed in terms of `DateTime` objects, considering that the underlying problem seems to be just determining whether the scheduled time of a sporting match falls within a given window of time. Using `DateTime` objects is but one way of addressing the problem, but is not the only way. In that sense the question may fall under the heading of [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

In fact, I find the use of `DateTime` objects complicates the problem unnecessarily. It's easier to express each time as simply a two-element array that contains the hour and minute. For example, the time-window that extends from 12:30 (24-hour clock) to 22:00 that evening could be expressed as the range:<sup>1</sup>

```
window = [12, 30]..[22, 0]
```

Event times could be defined similarly:<sup>2</sup>

```
event_time = [15, 45]..[19, 30]
```

For convenience, I will refer to the two-element arrays that are the endpoints of these ranges as simply "times".

An important consideration is that the start and end time of a sporting event does not necessarily fall on the same day. An example would be a tournament at which matches must fall within a window between 12:30 (24 hour clock) and 1:00 (AM) the following day. This is not unusual. This time-window would be expressed:

```
window = [12, 30]..[1, 0]
```

I assume:

- end times are less than 24 hours after their corresponding start times; and
- the time-window is the same every day.

Adjustments could of course be made to the code below if either assumption does not hold.

**Code**

Let's construct a method `valid?` that returns `true` (else `false`) if a given event falls within a given time-window:

```
def valid?(event_time, window)
  e = time_to_mins(event_time.begin)..time_to_mins(event_time.end)
  w = time_to_mins(window.begin)..time_to_mins(window.end)
  if w.begin <= w.end
    w.cover?(e)
  else
    (w.begin <= e.begin || e.begin <= w.end) &&
    (w.begin <= e.end   || e.end   <= w.end)
  end
end
```

```
def time_to_mins(time_arr)
  60 * time_arr.first + time_arr.last
end
```

**Examples**

```
time_to_mins [ 0, 10]              #=> 10 
time_to_mins [22, 30]              #=> 1350
```

```
window = [ 9, 30]..[22, 30]

valid?([13, 45]..[16, 30], window) #=> true 
valid?([ 8, 45]..[11, 30], window) #=> false 
valid?([22, 15]..[ 0, 15], window) #=> false
```

```
window = [12, 30]..[1, 0]

valid?([16, 15]..[19, 30], window) #=> true 
valid?([22, 45]..[ 0, 30], window) #=> true 
valid?([ 0, 15]..[ 0, 45], window) #=> true 
valid?([22, 45]..[ 1, 30], window) #=> false 
valid?([ 0, 15]..[ 1, 45], window) #=> false
```

<sup>1. If desired, one might alternatively express times as hashes, such as `{ hour: 12, min: 30, sec: 0 }`.</sup>

<sup>2. Information for each event might be held in a larger data structure, such as `event = { start_date: [2020, 2, 7], time_block: [[22, 45, 0]..[ 0, 30, 0]], player_1: 'R. Federer', player_2: 'R. Nadal' }`, using only `event[:time_block]` in the above calculation.</sup>